# prevent click and drag multi selection in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

How can I disable the click-drag multi selection in fabricjs?

In this image you can see the selection area with a red border:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5olYf.jpg

I want to prevent that kind of selection, but still allow single object selections.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a property on `fabric.Canvas` objects called `selection` which controls this group-selection behavior.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {width: 500, height: 500, selection: false});

//Or quite simply:
canvas.selection = false;
```

Comment: What if you are wanting to keep the ctrlKey multi select but not the select drag box?